# Returning every instance of whatever's between two strings in a file [Python 3]

Tags: python, string, list

What I'm trying to do is open a file, then find every instance of '[\x06I"' and '\x06;', then return whatever is between the two.

Since this is not a standard text file (it's map data from RPG maker) readline() will not work for my purposes, as the file is not at all formatted in such a way that the data I want is always neatly within one line by itself.

What I'm doing right now is loading the file into a list with read(), then simply deleting characters from the very beginning until I hit the string '[\x06I'.  Then I scan ahead to find '\x06;', store what's between them as a string, append said string to a list, then resume at the character after the semicolon I found.

It works, and I ended up with pretty much exactly what I wanted, but I feel like that's the worst possible way to go about it.  Is there a more efficient way?

My relevant code:

```
while eofget == 0:

    savor = 0
    while savor == 0 or eofget == 0:
        if line[0:4] == '[\x06I"':
            x = 4
            spork = 0
            while spork == 0:
                x += 1
                if line[x] == '\x06':
                    if line[x+1] == ';':
                        spork = x
                        savor = line[5:spork] + "\n"
                        line = line[x+1:]
                        linefinal[lineinc] = savor
                        lineinc += 1
                elif line[x:x+7] == '@widthi':
                    print("eof reached")
                    spork = 1
                    eofget = 1
                    savor = 0
        elif line[x:x+7] == '@widthi':
            print("finished map " + mapname)
            eofget = 1
            savor = 0
            break
        else:
            line = line[1:]
```

You can just ignore the variable names.  I just name things the first thing that comes to mind when I'm doing one-offs like this.  And yes, I am aware a few things in there don't make any sense, but I'm saving cleanup for when I finalize the code.

When eofget gets flipped on this subroutine terminates and the next map is loaded.  Then it repeats.  The '@widthi' check is basically there to save time, since it's present in every map and indicates the beginning of the map data, AKA data I don't care about.

Comment: Can you attach some input string example?

Comment: How are you reading into a list using `read()`?  You say that `readlines()` is not suitable.

Comment: Do you always expect to have an instance of  '[\x06I"' followed by an instance of '\x06;', or are there instances where there is a '[\x06I"' and no corresponding '\x06;' exists even up to the end of the file?

Comment: cdarke: readline() is not suitable because it looks for a line break.  Line breaks do exist in this file, but they correspond to nothing in particular and often split the data I need.  It's a consequence of trying to apply text file logic to proprietary code.

zehnpaard: Yes, the '[\x06I"' marker seems to denote any number of things, so relying entirely on it is unsafe.  In fact, I found a few instances where even with the '\x06;' marker I get some unwanted data.  I don't really know why, but it's rare enough that it's acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel this is a natural case to use regular expressions.  Using the [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) method:

```
>>> s = 'testing[\x06I"text in between 1\x06;filler text[\x06I"text in between 2\x06;more filler[\x06I"text in between \n with some line breaks \n included in the text\x06;ending'

>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('\[\x06I"(.+?)\x06;', re.DOTALL)
>>> print(p.findall(s))
['text in between 1', 'text in between 2', 'text in between \n with some line breaks \n included in the text']
```

The regex string `'\[\x06I"(.+?)\x06;'`can be interpreted as follows:

> Match as little as possible (denoted by `?`) of an undetermined number of unspecified characters (denoted by `.+`) surrounded by `'[\x06I"'` and `'\x06;'`, and only return the enclosed text (denoted by the parentheses around `.+?`)

Adding [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) in the compile makes the `.?` match line breaks as well, allowing multi-line text to be captured.

Comment: What's the merit of regex vs split?  I hear people advocating regex ALL the time, but to me it seems largely redundant.  But I'm the newbie, so I'm guessing I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm definitely not in the 'advocate regex all the time' camp, as it can often descend into unreadable code.  But in instances like this, I think the main benefits are terseness (minor benefit) and declarative nature of the code (major benefit).  Terseness in that it's a very short snippet of code that actually takes very little time to write if you are comfortable with regular expressions.  Declarative in that the regex string simply expresses exactly what you want the output to be, and leaves the actual mechanics to the regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

I would use split():

```
fulltext = 'adsfasgaseg[\x06I"thisiswhatyouneed\x06;sdfaesgaegegaadsf[\x06I"this is the second what you need \x06;asdfeagaeef'

parts = fulltext.split('[\x06I"')        # split by first label
results = []
for part in parts:                       
   if '\x06;' in part:                   # if second label exists in part
      results.append(part.split('\x06;')[0])  # get the part until the second label

print results
```

Comment: You know, I somehow forgot that split would split EVERY instance of the demarcator (or whatever the hell the word is), not just the first one.  This is a much better solution than what I did.

Comment: I ended up using the regex option above so I could practice using regex, but to anyone who stumbles upon this question, this is an equally valid answer.